# add third parameter to wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have url http://domain.com/real-estate-news/phuket-luxury-property-in-high-demand-ms
Where "real-estate-news" is category and "phuket-luxury-property-in-high-demand-ms" is the post name . 
when I print $wp_query->query_vars['name']; it gives the post slug and $wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] gives the category slug.

I want to generate a new url like http://domain.com/real-estate-news/phuket-luxury-property-in-high-demand-ms/xyz

and want to get xyz in query var like

```
    echo $wp_query->query_vars['name']; // print "phuket-luxury-property-in-high-demand-ms"
    echo $wp_query->query_vars['category_name']; // print "real-estate-news"
    echo $wp_query->query_vars['section']; //print "xyz"
```

How to add section query var in wordpress please help me

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Custom Post Type? If it is, you have more options than not. Within the register_post_type()'s array you can enter an  argument for 'rewrite' to change the slug name and hack in specific rewrite rules for that particular CPT. I have put this project away because of its complexity and if you find an answer I'd love to hear it. Here is my notes on the matter.

```
register_post_type(array(
//options
'rewrite'    => array( 
'slug'       => 'beach', //a slug used to identify the post type in URLs.
'with_front' => false,
'feed'       => true,  
'pages'      => true 
),
```

[dreamdare.org](http://dreamdare.org/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-wordpress-custom-post-type-permalink-404-error/)

[shibashake.com1](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks%20permastruct)

[shibashake.com2](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2)

Beware of wp.tutsplus very often misinformation is offered there by authors themselves.

[wp.tutsplus.com](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/)

Comment: No, this is not custom post type. this is simple post

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to do this is adding a rewrite rule.

This will look very similar to the one that custom post type creates but also receives a third parameter.
so in your case the rewrite rule would look like this

```php
add_rewrite_rule( 
  // post-type      | post-slug          | section           
  '^real-state-news/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/([^/]+)/?$',
  //                                                    | Here the section is added
  'index.php?post_type=real-state-news&name=$matches[1]&section=$matches[3]',
  'top'
);

//You then need to add a tag to it
add_rewrite_tag('%section%','([^&]+)');

// At this point, you should be able to grab that param
get_query_var('section')
```